# Can you safely have multiple pneumatic regulators in series to step down the pressure to a desired level?

Tags: compressor, regulator

I'm very new to pneumatics. I have recently acquired a 100psi compressor for use in my home wood workshop and would also like to use it for a small airbrush for painting. The target PSI range for the airbrush would be from 20-40 psi.

The regulator attached to my compressor starts to leak air when the pressure is reduced to around 60psi. Would it be safe/recommended to add another regulator to further step the pressure down to the target range? If not, are there any other solutions other than buying a separate compressor for the airbrush?

Comment: If the regulator on the compressor is supposed to go down to 20PSI, it sounds like what you've got should work. Have you considered having the regulator repaired/replaced so that it functions as it should? If you're going to have to buy a 2nd regulator, may as well get this one working right instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Putting air pressure regulators in series is not dangerous, as long as no part of the series is set to provide pressure greater than the remaining part of the series' maximum pressure.

At my former workplace in a cabinet shop with a shop-wide pressure-regulated air system, I have added an extra air pressure regulator at my station to drop air pressure to a needed level. In fact many air-driven machines have their own regulators to control pressure for the machine.